# Failure to update document in MongoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, axios

I cant figure it out how to update a document in .net web api. I read many tutorials on the net but still no success. One of them is [this site](https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/08/14/mongodb-in-net-part-6-updating-documents/%22this%20site%22).

```
data: () => {
    return {
        templates: [],
        newTemplate: '',
        title: 'Choose a template',
        selected: {},
        chosen: {
            Id: '5a3cd8e0762cb02118232752',
            max: '5',
            rules:'2'
        },
    };
},
```

Method to send data to api

```
updateTemplate: function (_id) {
                axios({
                    method: 'put',
                    url: 'http://localhost:57802/api/updateleavetemplate',
                    params: { Id: _id },
                    data: {
                        id: this.chosen.Id,
                        max: this.chosen.max,
                        rules: this.chosen.rules
                    }
                }).then(function (response) { console.log(response); })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            },
```

API Controller

```
[Route("api/updateleavetemplate/")]
[HttpPut]
public void UpdateLeave(String Id, LeavesTemplate UpdatedModel)
{
    _LeavesTemplateRepository.EditLeavesTemplate(Id, UpdatedModel);
}
```

Edit method from the repository

```
public void EditLeavesTemplate(String Id, LeavesTemplate leavestemplate)
{
    LeavesTemplate t = FindLeavesTemplateById(new ObjectId(Id));
    t.max = leavestemplate.max;
    t.rules = leavestemplate.rules;
    var filter = Builders<LeavesTemplate>.Filter.Eq(s => s.Id, leavestemplate.Id);
    var result = context.LeavesTemplates.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, t);

}
```

Comment: when debugging are you getting data in `EditLeavesTemplate()` ?

Comment: @derloopkat i changed the code in the repository to `LeavesTemplate z = new LeavesTemplate();
            z.rules = leavestemplate.rules;
            z.max = leavestemplate.max;

            z.Id = ObjectId.Parse(Id);
            ReplaceOneResult e = context.LeavesTemplates.ReplaceOne(Builders<LeavesTemplate>.Filter.Eq(r => r.Id, z.Id), z, new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true });
            Console.WriteLine(e.IsAcknowledged);`. Now every other fields has been replaced to null. only defined ones are saved. Changing ReplaceOne to UpdateOne does not help either.

Comment: edit your question and update code there, don´t need to post it as comment or answer

Answer (score 0):

I just replace the method in the repository by the following code below:

```
public void EditLeavesTemplate(String Id, LeavesTemplate leavestemplate)
        {
            LeavesTemplate z = FindLeavesTemplateById(new ObjectId(Id));
            z.rules = leavestemplate.rules;
            z.max = leavestemplate.max;    
            z.Id = ObjectId.Parse(Id);
            ReplaceOneResult e = context.LeavesTemplates.ReplaceOne(Builders<LeavesTemplate>.Filter.Eq(r => r.Id, z.Id), z, new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true });
            Console.WriteLine(e.IsAcknowledged);

        }
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, it is usually considered good practice to add an explanation of what your code does. This allows for developers who are not knowledgeable in this area to understand what is going on in the code and helps them to learn how to solve the problem by them selves in the future.